# Stop Firebase processes on previous page in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a React Native project, I have a problem. On the example home page, I am listening to the firebase table in useEffect. When I log out and go to the login page, the firebase process on the home page still works and gives an error because there is no user id. How can I stop Firebase processes on the home page when I'm logged out?

```
useEffect(() => {
  const userRef = database().ref('messages')
    .child(session.userId)
    .child(session.fbid);

  const onChildChanged = userRef.on(
    'child_changed',
    snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot)
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
  );

  return () => {
    userRef.off('child_changed', onChildChanged);
  };
}, [session.fbid, session.userId, navigation]);
```

> [Error: [database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.]

Answer (score 1):

It's required to check user authentication status before executing Firebase authentication-based features.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Get current authenticated user
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  // Listen to data changes when user is authenticated only.
  if (user) {
    const userRef = database()
      .ref("messages")
      .child(session.userId)
      .child(session.fbid);
    const onChildChanged = userRef.on(
      "child_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot);
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  return () => {
    user && userRef.off("child_changed", onChildChanged);
  };
}, [session.fbid, session.userId, navigation, user]);
```